# How to compare range in excel and generate output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table showing data (input)

[image]

I need output automated in (%) cell.

Once i select cat and amount (%) should come automatically based on the table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per your tags. Then the following formula will work for your requirements.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(H2,TEXTBEFORE(A2:A5,{" ","+"})+0,FILTER(B2:E5,H1=B1:E1),"NA",-1)
```

---

[image]

Comment: =xlookup(C7,TEXTBEFORE(A3:A6,{" ","+"})+0,FILTERS(B3:F6,B7=A2:F6),"NA",-1)

Comment: I am unable to get FILTER function any suggestion

Comment: @Sai Then use this `=INDEX(INDEX(B2:E5,,MATCH(H1,B1:E1,0)),MATCH(H2,LEFT(A2:A5,5)+0,1))` and let me know if that worked

Comment: Not working bro

Comment: @Sai you need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode.

Comment: This is `=INDEX($B$2:$E$5,MATCH($H2,LEFT($A$2:$A$5,5)+0,1),MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$E$1,0))`